# Creating an XML document in order to create a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am using the following to create a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

so far my code is as follows:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


require("dbinfo.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error());
}


// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can not use db : " . mysqli_error());
}

// Search the rows in the locations table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysqli_query($query);

$result = mysqli_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("location");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

When I run this I get the following error's:

```
    Notice: Undefined index: lat in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 11
 Notice: Undefined index: lng in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 12
 Notice: Undefined index: radius in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 13
 Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 28
 Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 30 Can not use db :
```

Can anyone help me to make sense of this or point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing the lat, lng and radius parameters in the URL?

Comment: Nah thats the bit I'm confused by the most. I didn't think at this point I needed to do that as I just want to create an XML document for now as this is the first step. I'm not completely sure how these should be passed in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: lat in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined index: lng in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: radius in /customers/b/7/e/tournamentfinder.co.uk/httpd.www/test/genxml.php on line 13
```

Indicate that you need to pass "reasonable" values for lat/lng/radius in the query string (e.g. ?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25000) as stated in [the tutorial you reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#outputxml):

**Checking That the XML Output Works**

> Call this PHP script from the browser to make sure it's producing valid XML. If you suspect there's a problem with connecting to your database, you may find it easier to debug if you remove the line in the file that sets the header to the text/xml content type, as that usually causes your browser to try to parse XML and may make it difficult to see your debugging messages.
>
> If the script is working correctly and **you append reasonable sample query parameters to the URL (e.g. ?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25)**, you should see XML output like this ([phpsqlsearch_expectedoutput.xml](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlsearch/phpsqlsearch_expectedoutput.xml)):

Answer (score 0):

Being new to coding, I was puzzled by this too, but the answer is really simple:

All you have to do is add something like `?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25` onto the end of the URL of your PHP file, when you navigate to it in your browser.
This makes the PHP script use these parameters, put them into your SQL query where you see the `'%s'` placeholders, then search your table, and spit out the answer to your query.

I had seen stuff like this added to web addresses before, but had no idea that is what it was doing (everyday's a schoolday...!)

For reference, the URL I put in my browser was:

```
http://localhost/user/xml_output.php?lat=49.860980&lng=0.681800&radius=7
```

as I am using my own location data.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the values, you should probably code in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables into your answer, as appropriate.